# conditions for navigation between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am working with the project of ios and doing well in it. But now i stuck at one place where i am having three views (Say 1stview, 2ndview, 3rdview). I am navigating to second view from first view and third view using the code line below.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:first view animated:YES];
```

How can i check on second view wheather i am navigating from first view or third view. So that i can use particular condition on it.
 So please help me out regarding this issue. Your help will be much appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a variable in second View controller. When you are creating the object of it, set proper value into it. Later on when it will get pushed, you can use that value to take proper decisions.

In the file of FirstViewController you will write below lines:

```
SecondController *controller = [[SecondController alloc]init];
controller.flag = 1; //That means you came here from viecontroller 1
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

In the file of ThirdViewcontroller you will write below lines:

```
SecondController *controller = [[SecondController alloc]init];
controller.flag = 3; //That means you came here from viecontroller 3
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to arrange thing so that the 2ndView doesn't know about 1stView or 3rdView, but instead just changes it's behavior according to how it was configured. So, let's say that when you're navigating to 2ndView from 1stView, 2nd should display with a green background and when you get there from 3rd it should use blue instead. Rather than telling 2nd which controller preceded it, have the preceding controller just tell 2nd what background color to use. Same goes for any other aspect of 2ndView's behavior.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can change 1st or 3rd without having to change anything in 2nd, and you can later add a 4thView or 5thView that also use 2ndView without having to change 2ndView.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the method – navigationController:willShowViewController:animated: from the UINavigationControllerDelegate Protocol Reference. Inside this method you can check the navigation stack to get the current view controller using several properties of UINavigationController. An example would be access the visibleViewController property.

As @Apurv pointed out you need some sort of identifier mechanism to be able to know which view controller the call came from. e.g.: viewController.view.tag